# Change Array Object and array to new Array Object

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an Array object which is dynamic

```
this.rating.data = {[4, 1, 8, 3, 3]};
```

I have an Array

```
this.rating.labels = ["In", "Lo", "Me", "Hi", "Cri"];
```

However, data will be zero in a lot of case cases
Ex (if data of "In" is zero, the labels will be not displayed in array)

```
this.rating.data = {[1, 8, 3, 3]};
```

and

```
this.rating.labels = ["Lo", "Me", "Hi", "Cri"];
```

I try to handle and create a new Array Object new with define but I can not handle it

```
[{
"In": 0,
"Lo": 1,
"Me": 8,
"Hi" : 3,
"Cri": 3,}]
```

Comment: `this.rating.data = {[4, 1, 8, 3, 3]};` that is not valid JavaScript syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the Array.reduce function for this case.
https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

With reduce you can transform a Array in basically everything you want:

```js
let rating = [4, 1, 8, 3, 3]
let labels = ["In", "Lo", "Me", "Hi", "Cri"]
let result = rating.reduce((acc,value,idx)=>{
  acc[labels[idx]]= value; 
  return acc
},{})

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not very familar with Javascript, but you could try to do a FOR loop to combine the two array data together then add them to your new loop, one by one.

Hope this help, sorry this is not the actual answer.